# How to get the process name from a Windows dump file?

Tags: visual-studio, coredump, crash-dumps

If I open a .dmp file with Visual Studio, I am presented with a summary about the dump:

[image]

Is there a way I can access the value for the "Process Name" field through the command line (i.e. a tool like `windbg.exe`, `dumpbin.exe`)?

Comment: You can use [`dumpchk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dumpchk) and look for the `.exe` name under `ModuleListStream`.

Comment: @dxiv thanks, that did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Run **!analyze -v**, in the output, you can see process name listed-
For example:
PROCESS_NAME:  RuntimeBroker.exe